# Can't get html source code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the HTML source code from a url and then pass it in to a string.
After I press the debug button it asks me if I want to open the debuger (the code compile fine.)

The debuger: **ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2180**

says e > cause > "java.lang.NullPointerException" and "detailMessage    null".

So I understands that this is a NullPointerException but cant see where.

Amd the only thing the LogCat says is:

```
08-14 00:34:10.437: E/Trace(1784): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-14 00:34:10.437: I/System.out(1784): Sending WAIT chunk
08-14 00:34:10.437: I/dalvikvm(1784): Debugger is active
08-14 00:34:10.644: I/System.out(1784): Debugger has connected
08-14 00:34:10.644: I/System.out(1784): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 00:34:11.867: I/System.out(1784): debugger has settled (1300)
08-14 00:34:13.428: D/dalvikvm(1784): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

I don't really know what more info to give you. :/

The code I use for this is (this is the GetCode class)

```
    public String html;

public void getSourceCode() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(pisjjgujku50by55lpbdl1a2))/design1.aspx?schoolid=18200&code=83310");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    html = "";
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();
    System.out.println("html");

}
```

Then in the main class I just try to print the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        doStuff();
}



private void doStuff() {
    try {
        getcode.getSourceCode();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(getcode.html);
}
```

Comment: can you share a more detailed stack trace ? Your network operation is in the main thread, you need to execute network operations in a different thread, something like Android Async Task

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to improve your chances on getting the answer you are looking for. In particular, you should ask a *specific* question. What exactly are you having trouble with? Does your code compile? If not, show us the compiler error. If it does compile, what happens when you run your app? How does the behavior differ from what you expect? There are lots of people here at SO that are willing to help you as long as you are willing provide the information we need in order to do so.

Comment: p.s. It is unclear how the logcat message you posted is related to your app. Please explain further, perhaps by including more of the pertinent information from the logcat.

Comment: Immediate problem I see is you're performing blocking network operations on the UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for quick network operations or a separate thread. I recommend a separate thread here. And as others said, improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are still not providing enough information for an accurate diagnosis.  You should supply:

- a complete and accurate description of what is happening
- the complete stacktrace for the exception, including the line numbers
- all of the code that "connects the dots"; e.g. when and where is getSourceCode called.

---

Having said that, I can see two possible causes of NPE's in the (partial) code you have provided:

- If `getSourceCode()` is not called, then the `html` variable could be `null` when the `onCreate` method is called.
- If the Response object returned by `client.execute(request)` is an error response (i.e. the status is a 4xx or 5xx response code), then `response.getEntity()` will return `null`.  I think this can also happen if the response has no content.